# Make all images displayed in single.php a certain size

Tags: images

I’m working on a fashion blog with **a lot** of images. I’ve imported all posts from Blogger to WordPress and it seems to have left me with images which have a size added on to the end of their `src`:

`http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/beach-babe-300x200.jpeg`

However the `href` of the surrounding `a` tag is set to:

`http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/beach-babe.jpeg`

Is this something to do with WordPress or is it something from images imported from Blogger? How can I tell WordPress that I want to display the a certain image size on the single post page (**single.php**).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this page in the Codex for an intro to how WordPress works with images, specifically the Image Size section:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages

not sure what the import from Blogger did exactly, but you can start by attempting to change the image size in the editor.

Comment: Thanks but this wasn’t what I was looking for as there is literally thousands of images to edit. Blogger appended the image size to the end of image names so I ended up just downloading the wp-posts.sql file and editing it directly. I found all the images with sizes appended using a regular expression search (thanks Sublime Text). The regular expression I used was `-([0-9]{3})x([0-9]{3}).jpg` for anybody that’s interested.